# Matplotlib Image fit to equation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to output equation image, but I want the figure size fit to the equation, how to adjust it?

Thanks,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convert(string):
    if string[0] != '$' and string[-1] != '$':
        string = '$' + string + '$'
    plt.text(0.01, 0.8, string, fontsize=50)
    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())
    plt.savefig('latex.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saving a figure that represents a string, it might be better to remove the black frame box and make the background transparent, which is done by adding these two lines,

```
plt.figure(frameon=False)
plt.axes(frameon=0)
```

To make the figure size fit the equation, save the figure this way,

```
plt.savefig('D:/latex.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Finally, its better to remove the figure from memory after saving it, and this is done by adding this line,

```
plt.close()
```

So the new code would be,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convert(string):
    plt.figure(frameon=False)
    plt.axes(frameon=0)
    if string[0] != '$' and string[-1] != '$':
        string = '$' + string + '$'
    plt.text(0.01, 0.8, string, fontsize=50)
    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())
    plt.savefig('D:/latex.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

With the new method above, if you execute,
 `convert('y=3333333333333333333333333333333x')`
You should get the following result,

[image]

The figure also fits the height, if you run the command,

```
    convert('y=1x\ny=2x\ny=3x\ny=4x\ny=5x\ny=6x\ny=7x\ny=8x\n
               y=9x\ny=10y\ny=11x\ny=22x\ny=33x\ny=44x\ny=55x\ny=66x\ny=77x')
```

The figure  would be,

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I got result image is fit the width of equation, but the height is 500px, does it fit the height also?

Comment: Yes, it does, the 500px is by default, but if you have a lot of line breaks in your string, the figure height would change to fit the string, I edited my answer to illustrate this :)